# Jquery datepicker- Prevent to submit form before date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I got Jquery UI Datepicker that work well, but one important issue make me serious problems.Problem is when user dont select date from datepicker and submit query, external service throw error, otherwise everything is ok. How to prevent that, disable submit button if date is not selected?Any ideas on how to do that. I put code on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ljuboja/6Pcm9/5/) One more question.How to prevent users to select previous date than tommorow date and set tommorow as default date thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code snippet. I stripped down unimportant code and commented each line I added. Also updated jsfiddle example.

```
//variable to indicate was date selected or not
var dateSelected = false;
$('#date').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        ...
        //set to true on date selection
        dateSelected = true;
    },
    //minimal date to select (today)
    minDate: new Date( (new Date()).getTime() + 3600*24*1000 )
})
... 
//return false when date wasn't selected to prevent submission   
$('form').submit(function(){
    if (!dateSelected) {
        alert('Choose date please');
    }
    return dateSelected;
});
```

Comment: Thx for answer, i did not try in my code, i want to see on jsfiddle but i cant see any update as you said, ewhat is the problem.I pretty new on fiddle, maybe my false somehow..

Comment: Great work! Thx.Is it possible to give user some cue what is happening, some simple pop up to say must insert date ..
For part of my question about minimal date to select is possible to be tommorow date?

Comment: I added alert call to the form submit callback. You can replace it with something more fancy. Also changed code for minDate, now it's tomorrow.

Comment: sorry my js is weak, how to substitute alert with some css pop up.Give me some clue.Css is not problem, just how to hook it in js

Comment: @bjornd have problem with alert popup, it shows up if date is selected and if is not